# FR_DISK_ERROR always is returned by f_open

Tags: c, stm32, hal, fatfs, cubemx

My team has been working on a project that contains a SD card based on Standard Library. Recently we've decided to migrate to HAL and it started.

Fortunately, All part of our project were changed as well as possible to HAL and they're working great but we don't know why SD card doesn't work well.

We have not changed peripheral's configuration clocks, but we had to change "clock frequency of the SDMMC controller" to 1.5MHz in HAL while it was 24MHz in STDLibrary. Because, it didn't work at all.

In addition, our customers are using a wide range of SD card types and all of them are OK but not great. I mean, `FR_DISK_ERR` is returned a lot in during of working but our device tries to get `FR_OK`.

Unfortunately, we always receive `FR_DISK_ERR` in some SD cards while, it worked all the time in our STDLibrary version.

Furthermore, we've found if "f_mount" function was called once and after that you take away the SD card and put it again, it will never work until you reset your microcontroller.

My microcontroller is **STM32F427VI** and *SDIO* configured as same as this:

```
 hsd.Instance = SDIO;

 hsd.Init.ClockEdge = SDIO_CLOCK_EDGE_RISING;

 hsd.Init.ClockBypass = SDIO_CLOCK_BYPASS_DISABLE;

 hsd.Init.ClockPowerSave = SDIO_CLOCK_POWER_SAVE_DISABLE;

 hsd.Init.BusWide = SDIO_BUS_WIDE_1B;

 hsd.Init.HardwareFlowControl = SDIO_HARDWARE_FLOW_CONTROL_DISABLE;

 hsd.Init.ClockDiv = 14;
```

and it's working with 4bits wide bus.

Also, my device's clock is 96MHz and "APB2 Peripheral Clock" is 48MHz.

***Edited:***

As for re-inserting the card - I did initial again by recalling f_mount when `FR_DISK_ERR` was returned by f_open. I did it until giving `FR_OK` but it's never returned `FR_OK` in this case.

I realized f_mount doesn't initial SDIO for second time as dear Jacek Ślimok said.

Because there's a flag that doesn't let 'SD_initialize' be recall again (SD_initialize function includes BSP_SD_Init).

**Here is the *diskio.c*'s code:**

```
DSTATUS disk_initialize (
    BYTE pdrv /* Physical drive nmuber to identify the drive */
)

{

 DSTATUS stat = RES_OK;

 if(disk.is_initialized[pdrv] == 0)

 {

     disk.is_initialized[pdrv] = 1;

     stat = disk.drv[pdrv]->disk_initialize(disk.lun[pdrv]);

 }

 return stat;

}
```

Now I used `SD_PowerON` and `SD_InitCard` before recalling f_mount and it worked correctly now.
It's a bug, isn't it?

But other problems have still remained. It doesn't work with 24MHz clock at all and `FR_DISK_ERR` is still returned by some SD cards.

***Edited (2020/02/24):***

Finally, it worked when I updated my HAL Library to STM32Cube_FW_F4_V1.24.2. But HAL still doesn't work as well as Standard Peripheral. For example, I can't set 'ClockDiv' to '0' (24MHz) yet. It doesn't work at all. Now I set 'ClockDiv' to '1' (16MHz) that's not good enough for my project but I have to. Or if you take SDCard away and insert it again when program is working you can not init FATFS with f_mount. It's not going to work at all. You have to init SDIO Peripheral again by yourself. Unfortunately, now I can't put any time for getting more detail about what's going on in my schedule. Maybe in future.

Comment: As for re-inserting the card - that's because it needs to be initialized again, then `f_mount`-ed. By initialization I don't mean GPIO / DMA initialization (which you can probably omit and get away with it) but the SD commands that need to be sent to the card again after it's inserted but before filesystem gets mounted. In particular - see `HAL_SD_InitCard` and the functions inside that send SD commands - mainly `SD_PowerON` and `SD_InitCard`.

Comment: Related: https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BEZwxPSQT/setting-up-sdio-for-the-stm32f103zc-fatfs-frdiskerr-error

Comment: In st communtiy they said this method works to solve similar problem:  https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkWceSAF/stm32f411re-stm32cube-fatfs-sdio-sdcard-always-returns-frdiskerr

Comment: Thank you, but I've done everything that they said.

Comment: @AliEsmailpor, see these links may related.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100378/f-mount-returns-fa-disk-err?rq=1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681083/fatfs-cant-initialize-the-sd-card?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835115/cannot-mount-sd-using-fatfs-on-stm32

Comment: @AliEsmailpor Instead of wasting more than a month experimenting with this bloatware HAL you would write your own register level driver in one week (if you do not have experience) or in one day (if you bin the HAL and gain experience). An additional bonus: you know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

disk.is_initialized[0] =0;  // force reinit

Before mounting. That's the easy way to support hot plugged sd card.